# Term for intersection of lattice and convex region?

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis, integer-lattices

Is there a special term or convenient phrase for the restriction of a convex region to points of a lattice?

This is motivated by wanting to talk about the feasible points of a discrete problem.  I'd like to say the points form a convex region, but since they are a subset of the usual integer lattice in several dimensions, that's not AFAIK correct terminology.

I note that [convex lattice polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_lattice_polytope) refers to the (connected) convex region and not to lattice points contained therein.

Comment: If there were, it would show up in the theory of Ehrhart polynomials (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial), and I'm not aware of one in that field, so...

Comment: Yes, I was thinking back over discussions of Pick's Thm. I'd read/heard, and drawing a blank.  But at my age(!) that's not best evidence.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: No offense, but I've rolled back your retagging.  The specialized tags don't reflect my topic as well as the broader ones I chose.

Comment: @hardmath The (lattice) tag is deprecated and [tag:integer-lattices] or [tag:lattice-orders] or [tag:lattices-in-lie-groups] should be used instead (whichever fits). See [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/3187#3187) for details. I don't really see the point of creating a new tag called (convex), when we already have [tag:convex-sets].

Comment: @MartinSleziak:  Very well then. Although convex analysis has a substantially more specific meaning than convex sets (and my question is not about analysis), I have rolled back to your tag edits.

Comment: It was discussed on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/3045#3045) whether [tag:convex-sets] and [tag:convex-analysis] should be made synonyms; it seems that the community consensus was that they should be.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I invite you to post your comment as an answer.  Although a "negative" answer, it will be gladly accepted.